# Check if OpenCV was compiled with GStreamer support in Cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, gstreamer, cmakelists-options

I need something like

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

if(OpenCV_WITH_GSTREAMER)
   message("has gstreamer")
   add_executable(stream src/main.cpp)
else()
   message("no gstreamer")
endif()
```

To compile certain binaries if OpenCV has GStreamer. Is there a variable like that I could read in CMakeLists? Open to alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible by examining cmake files from the OpenCV distribution package. However OpenCV within the `videoio` module offers a possibility to specify [VideoCapture API backend](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d). You could rely on that fact and for instance write a tiny program which would create a `cv::VideoCapture` object passing the `CAP_GSTREAMER` value as the `apiPreference` constructor's parameter and then examine whether OpenCV is compiled with the support for gstreamer or not based on the result of the `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened()` method. You could run such tiny application from your cmake files and based on its result decide whether compile those certain binaries or not. I would consider writing that tiny app in python for simplicity.